# Like the difference in rendering HTML entity encoding, how else do the 'Inspect Element' and 'View Source' of browsers differ?

Tags: html, browser, encoding

I do realize the difference regarding DOM manipulation changes from scripts. This is different.

I see that when the web server sends `&lt;script&gt;` ...
'Inspect Element' would show `<script>` whereas 'View Source' would show `&lt;script&gt;`.
(Verified with Firefox)

**Why have the two features been designed in a way to have this difference?**

**What differences of similar nature should one keep in mind?**
The thing is, Inspect Element seems a bit more convenient. :) Though, it would be good to know cases where View Source beats it.

Comment: If you want to see the server response, use "view source" if you want to see and modify the dom use inspector

Comment: Already discussed here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967324/difference-between-source-code-and-inspect-element

Comment: That link doesn't discuss about character encoding. It is mostly about differences from DOM manipulation.

Comment: Following from the previous comment, was there something so wrong in this question to get a downvote? Did I miss the proverbial 'manual'?

Answer (score 1):

Different tools for different jobs. When you inspect the source, you are looking at the actual written code or markup as it is delivered to the browser. When you use 'inspect element' you are looking at the computed values.

When you inspect an element, that's not the same as viewing the source tags as they are written. So in the source you will always see the HTML entity as it's spelled out but, in inspect element, you are looking at the actual element, not the entity/tag.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice summary.
Though, if not too much to ask...
1. can you elaborate on cases where source code and browser computed values differ (apart from DOM manipulations)?
2. and also how an HTML entity as it's spelled out can differ from the actual element rendered?

Comment: @Vyoam You can think of it like this. "View source" is like looking at the formula "x = 1+1". "Inspect element" is like looking at "x" and seeing "2". The former is used to create the element. The latter is the element itself.