# jQuery counting elements by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of code where I need to loop through all elements in a table with a specific class name (there will be only one element with this class per table row, a checkbox).  I am using jQuery's `$(".className").each( function () { });` functionality to do this.  The code works exactly as it should except for one issue.  I have a table with approx 600 rows and each row has a checkbox with the class so there are 600 checkbox elements with this class.  However when I try to loop through all these elements on 180 are found.  I have tried to do a count of these elements with the following code

```
var count =  $('.importCheck').length;
console.log("Number of elements = " + count);
```

And it still only fined approx 180 elements.  But if I view the source code of the table in the browser all the 600 rows and elements with the class are present.  Don't understand why this is failing to find all the elements with this class in the grid.
Any Ideas.

Here is the full method.

Thanks in advance.

```
function importCheckedOrders(){

// Display the loader.
$('#loadingDiv').addClass('cssLoader');
$('#loadingDivBackground').addClass('cssBackground');

var obj =   {};

var count =  $('.importCheck').length;  // Count how many rows to check as we want to start another process after 
console.log("Number of elements = " + count);

$("#importChecked").hide();  // Hide the button so the user can't hit it again (cause their still stupid).


//  the last one is checked and processed in the .each loop .
$(".importCheck").each(function(){

    if( $(this).prop("checked") ) // If checkbox is checked then add the movement.
    {
        var orderID     =   $(this).val();

        // var tempArr =   new Array();

        obj[orderID] = {
            orderID:        orderID,         //  ID of resource(or order) being dragged.
            orderDate:      $("#"+orderID+"_order_date").val(),
            orderType:      $("#"+orderID+"_orchid_type").val(),
            accountID:      $("#"+orderID+"_orchid_id").val(),
            currency:       $("#"+orderID+"_order_currency").val(),
            rate:           $("#"+orderID+"_order_rate").val(),
            bookedWith:     $("#"+orderID+"_order_booked").val(),
            ref:            $("#"+orderID+"_order_ref").val(),
            haz:            $("#"+orderID+"_order_haz").val()
        };

        $("#"+orderID+"_orderButton").hide();  // Hide the button so the user can't hit it again (cause their stupid).

    }

    if(!--count)
    { 
        var rootPath    =   $("#rootPath").val();    

        // Grab all the data to create a new transaction and post it.
        $.ajax({
            url:    rootPath+"edi/addOrderTicked",
            data:{
                    _token: $('meta[name="_orchid_token"]').attr('content'),
                    orders: JSON.stringify(obj), // stringfy object and pass it to the server for php processing.
                },
            type:   'post',
            success: function(data){

                $(data).each(function(a, b) {

                    $("#order_tr_"+b).hide(); // Hide the row.
                    $('#loadingDiv').removeClass('cssLoader');
                    $('#loadingDivBackground').removeClass('cssBackground');
                    $("#importChecked").show();

                });

            }

        });             

    }        

});       

}
```

Comment: you can do a $.each statement and use a counter variable

Comment: In the `$(data).each(...)` loop , maybe `$("#importChecked").show();` should be `$(".importChecked").show();` ?? Or `$(document).find(".importChecked").show();` if some are dynamically created by Ajax... For sure, `#` is wrong.

Comment: "But if I view the source code of the table..."  how?  Did you use view source or did you inspect elements?  Because view source will show you how the markup looked at page load, not how it has been modified since.  So if you are looking at view source it is entirely possible that the classes have been removed from some elements that originally had them.

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967324/difference-between-source-code-and-inspect-element

Comment: I agree with @Taplar, something is probably removing the elements or changing their classes dynamically.

Comment: Open up the console and use Javascript to double check - `document.getElementsByClassName('importCheck');` and then check the length of that array. You can even look and see what is inside of the array from the console, and you can figure out if your web page is actually missing items in the table. Maybe they load later on via ajax so you are not loading everything all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Have you the same result without jQuery ?

Length :

```
 Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.getElementsByClassName("MyClass")
 ).length
```

ForEach :

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(
 document.getElementsByClassName("MyClass")
).forEach(function(element, index, array){
   ... do stg ...
})
```

Comment: You don't need `[].slice.call`. You can just use `document.getElementsByClassName("MyClass").length`

Comment: Small side note, you can also use Array.prototype instead of [] to avoid creating a new array just for the sake of method access @Dafuck

Comment: Yeah true, its to keep continuity between the two function, .forEach doesn't work on HTMLCollections

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way and see what you get:

```
$.each(".importCheck",function(){
```

I know it *can* work the way you have it too, and I'm not exactly sure what the difference is.... But when one doesn't work I try the other. If this doesn't work, your code looks right, so maybe you need to check the table again and see if you actually have 600 elements.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/