# Using =ImportHTML\XML on an Infinite Scrolling table

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

I've been using Google Sheets to track my video game collection for a while now, and I've come to a point where it's starting to break when importing data from a certain site. I link from 2 sites, GameValueNow and VideoGamePriceCharting.

GVN's website works great, my code is

```
=QUERY(ImportHTML( "http://gamevaluenow.com/nintendo-nes" , "table" , 11 ), "SELECT Col3 where Col2="""&$B3&"""",0)
```

Which returns the price for a specified game. I also would like to do the same with VGPC and get an average price from the 2, however it's table only shows the first 50 results and has an infinite scroll, until the final result is posted.

I'm wondering if there is a way to preload the website using a script before running either importHTML or importXML so that I am able to query the all of the results and not just the first 50.

The website I am trying to import is:

https://www.pricecharting.com/console/nes?sort=name

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML are able to reach the content of the file pointed out by the URL set as argument of them so, if "preloading the website" through Google Apps Script could be possible that will not help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Do the importHTML/XML commands not just scrape through the page source and return the values they find?

When looking at the source code after initial landing, the table stops after 50 entries, however if I scroll down the source will begin to add rows. So wouldn't that alter the results of either command? Or am I mistaken and they work a completely different way?

Thanks again!

Comment: @mckgn I think that you call "source code" to the code shown on the elements tab of the browser developer tools but that isn't the source code that is the DOM which is dynamically modified by JavaScript.

Comment: @mckgn Maybe [Difference between source code and “inspect element”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18967324/1595451) will help to clarify this .