# Trying to add an ID to a class using Javascript, shows on Dev Tool but not in Source Code

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add the ID "extraattr" to a div that has a class named "prod-description-bdy". This class only appears once on the page.

I wrote the following code below and it works when I check it on Chrome Dev Tools but does not show when I do a "view source code".

Am I missing something in my code?

```
const elem = document.getElementsByClassName("prod-description-bdy")[0];

function myFunction() {
    elem.setAttribute("id", "extraattr");
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",myFunction);
```

Comment: “View Source Code” displays the static original source code when reading the HTML file. It has nothing to do with the current state of the DOM.

Comment: This is to be expected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between source code and "inspect element"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967324/difference-between-source-code-and-inspect-element) and [Is the HTML shown via 'View Source' different from the HTML shown in (Firebug) developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13070190/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's Javascript, which only runs once the page is loaded. Viewing the source code does not run the Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

What you see in the dev tool's inspector is the DOM, not the source. The DOM can change, the html that is sent to you from the server cannot.

[Document Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model#targetText=The%20Document%20Object%20Model%20(DOM,document%20with%20a%20logical%20tree.)

Answer (score 0):

The source code is exactly that--the source that your program runs from. It will no show any changes that are made at runtime.